# BeagleBone Black with Debian won't start autostart service to start server at reboot

Tags: node.js, sockets, service, beagleboneblack

I'm currently developing a Webserver on BeagleBone Black with Debian OS. The Webserver is implemented with Node.js and should run automatically once the BBB has been started. The Webserver is using socket.io (no bonescript or other libraries).

I'm new to this topic and i couldn't find anything helping. **Here's what i already tried and where i can't figure out how to go further:**

- I wrote a Shellscript which should be started from a service(systemd). If i start the Shellscript by hand, everything works fine. But when daemon tries to start it and use the **systemctl status server.service** i get the error

> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/server.service; enabled)
>   
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon, 20 Apr 2015 15:58:31 +00                00; 19s ago
>
> Process: 2106 ExecStart=/usr/bin/prepare.sh (code=exited, status=8)
>
> CGroup: name=systemd:/system/server.service
>
> module.js:340
>   throw err; Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'

I guess my service needs the node.js package but they aren't loaded to the point where BB starts my service. But i also don't know on which service i have to wait to start my server successfully

- I also tried to to move my prepare.sh to /etc/profile.d but it didn't work either

**Here's my server.service code**

```
[Unit]
Description=Autostart server
After=bonescript.socket bonescript-autorun.service apache2.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/prepare.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/tstellanova/7323116) i used

Comment: Maybe adding `WorkingDirectory=/your_proyect_directory` under `[Service]` will help.

Comment: At the first time i was using WorkingDirectory and it was the same result but i'll try it again. Maybe i had some false settings. Thank you for your reply.